# ST3: insert same character till end of line

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to insert the same character till the end of the line in Sublime Text 3? I would like to use this feature to structure my code by comments.

E.g. when coding in R I may want to have a comment "Load file" where the dashes go to the 80th column.

```
# Load file --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In other cases the comment may be longer, so the number of characters inserted should be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use and/or extend this simple plugin

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CommenterCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):        
        sel = self.view.sel()[0]
        line = self.view.line(sel)
        [row, currentColumn] = self.view.rowcol(line.end())
        while (currentColumn < 80):
            self.view.insert(edit, self.view.text_point(row,currentColumn), "-")
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
```

Example of the plugin triggered from the keyboard.

[image: Plugin]